# Compile error cause by NSAray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, uilabel

As you'll see from the code in the xcode project file there's a compile error at build time.

I'm trying to apply names for the indivudal image using the following code:

```
labelArray =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", nil];
    cell.label.text = [_labelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

This is using apples sample code for collection view but the principals are the same for my project.

Here's a drop box link for the compile error issue using an NSArray with a uilabel..

The error is:

Interface storyboard compile error.

Any thoughts on this would be great.

Cheers

Comment: Don't put stuff in Dropbox and expect people to look at it.  Copy/paste the error messages and relevant code sections into your question.  If you hurry you can get it done before your question is closed for lack of info.

Comment: Why are you referring to labelArray on one line, and _labelArray on another?

Comment: Ah, sorry, tried your suggestion with both underscores and still no avail.

Comment: what is the motherflippin' error?

Comment: Interface storyboard compile error. Also tried re-connecting

Comment: If this is a storyboard compiler error, it doesn't sound like it has anything to do with your code. Wouldn't that be about a storyboard?

Comment: What's the likely issue with the storyboard? Any thoughts? Works fine without the label attached.

Comment: For convenience: The error is: `...CollectionView/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboard: Couldn't compile connection: <IBCocoaTouchOutletCollectionConnection:0x7fd9ad627570  <IBProxyObject: 0x7fd9abd8e410> => labelArray (NSArray) => <IBUILabel: 0x7fd9ad5d4150>>`, and the `labelArray` outlet is declared: `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *labelArray` and in the storyboard the labelArray outlet is attached to a `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't kwow about your storyboard issue (it is impossible to say anything without seeing the storyboard, or, at least, how the outlet is bound), but there is another issue.
It seems like `labelArray` is an array of `UILabel`. But in the first line of your code, you are creating an array of `NSString`.